# Is the Latter Clause of an Action Simile Attributed to the Subject or Object Acted Upon?

Tags: subjects, comparisons, subordinate-clauses, objects, simile

In other (hopefully more graceful) words, are both of the following lines valid?

1. "A smiling Freddy flung the slimy papaya around *like a wet rag*."
2. "A smiling Freddy flung the slimy papaya around like *it's* a wet
   rag."

The first one sounds snappy and concise — but may sound like it's comparing an unassuming Freddy, literally, to a wet rag. Meanwhile, the second line draws a clearer, more plausible comparison, albeit at the expense of *smoothness* in rhythm, if you will.

What the hell do you guys think?! DAMN! heh

**P.S. Someone help me rephrase this awful question better.**

Comment: Shirley, you're not implying that a sentence in English can be ambiguous?

Comment: #2 would sound much better if you wrote "like it was a wet rag" (past tense). But that said, in this example at least, it's pretty clear that in #1, the comparison of the wet rag is with the papaya and not with the unassuming Freddy. I'm not sure there's a rule, because I can also imagine this: "A smiling Freddy flung the slimy papaya around like an overexcited money playing with a banana peel."